# Only USERID, PID, TIME, and COMMAND for specific user Shell Script

Tags: linux, process, ps

I have to get Only USERID, PID, TIME, and COMMAND for a specific user. I have tried

```
ps -u user1
```

But that display  `PID TTY TIME CMD`, but I dont want the Field TTY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL" as specified in `man ps`, like

```
$ ps -u user1 -ouid,pid,time,cmd
```